# Bug with play-services-maps on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-play-services

There was a following problem. I use google services to use maps. Generated an API key, added restrictions. But I got the following behavior: when I run the application on the Android Studio emulator, everything is displayed. But when launched on a physical device, only a dark screen and buttons for zooming in / out and the current geolocation are visible. At the same time, it shows correctly my current location in the logs, and when I click it, it also displays the coordinates. I think it might be related to the warning in the picture. Has anyone come across this issue and been able to resolve it?

I tried to generate a new key, added / removed all restrictions, signed the application, did everything according to the official documentation, as a result, there were no changes.

[Warning with update snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U9SM.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We suggest that you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community could help you better.